# Wordpress logo cuts off on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

My problem: When visiting [my website](http://www.slothcraft.com) on mobile, the logo does not resize, and it cuts off.

I have tried: I have tried adding some CSS code that I found online, but it did not do the trick for me unfortunately, it must have been using the wrong css selectors, but I am not very familiar with CSS/Responsive themes.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvGS1.jpg)

Comment: I forgot to mention, the URL of the website is at www.slothcraft.com

Comment: add `max-width: 100%` to the `img`

Comment: `.header #logo img {max-width: 100%;}`, then test it in your dev tool (F12) using Crtl+Shift+M (dev tool must be open)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanks so much man, worked right away!!